# ¿Cómo usar de manera eficiente subset y group_by?

Tags: r, r-dplyr

Tengo un df original enorme que contiene datos de temperatura y peso. Al hacer

```
ndatos <- df %>% 
  group_by(tt) %>%
  summarise(peso=mean(peso),
               n=n())%>%
  data.frame()
```

puedo ver que para cada categoría de temperatura tengo diferente número de observaciones, así:

```
df

Temp   Obs     Pesomedio

-3      782      40
-2      815      32
-1      3586     52
0       561      78
1       256      89
2       758      99
```

Lo que debo hacer es eliminar de cada categoría de temperatura el 1% de los valores de peso más altos y más bajos sobre la media del valor. No sé cómo hacerlo de forma sencilla y eficiente, porque lo primero que se me ha ocurrido es hacer un subset por categoría, luego sacar la media y luego eliminar manualmente los valores más altos y más bajos sin que estos superen el 2% del total... pero esto me llevaría horas o días.

Espero haberme explicado y que me puedan ayudar. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuando hablas de remover el 1% de los superiores e inferiores a la media? te refieres a cualquier 1% o a los valores más alejados de la media.

Comment: Si, me refiero a los valores más alejados de la media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que de cada categoría de temperatura quieres eliminar el 1% de valores extremos. En términos más técnicos, sería dejar los 98 percentiles centrales, eliminando el percentil 1 y el 100 de cada grupo. En este caso deberías tener una reducción de la n del 2% en total.

En ese caso una solución muy simple sería:

```
# Retomo los datos de la solución de Patricio Moracho para mantener la reproducibilidad
data.frame(temp = rep(-3:2, 100), 
                 peso = rep(40:99, 100)) -> df
df %>% 
   group_by(temp) %>%
   mutate(orden = ntile(peso, 100)) %>% 
   #Creo una columna con el percentil al que corresponde cada valor de peso
   filter(!orden %in% c(1, 100))
   #Filtro excluyendo los percentiles 1 y 100
```

Obtengo `n=5880`. Considerando que la `n` original es 6000 entonces se filtraron 120 filas, las 10 de mayor valor y las 10 de menor valor de cada uno de los 6 grupos.

Comment: Cuando dices que te quedas con un 99% de los datos de manera aleatoria, ese 1% que quitas cumple con la condición de que pertenezca a los más alejados de la media por ser máximos o mínimos?

Comment: No, es un 1% aleatorio dentro de cada grupo. No me había quedado clara la pregunta. Más tarde la corrijo para que elimine el 1% de casos extremos.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Un ejemplo básico
data.frame(temp = rep(-3:2, 100), 
           peso = rep(40:99, 100)) -> df

df %>% 
    # agrupamos por temp
    group_by(temp) %>% 
    # Determinamos si es superior o no a la media para el grupo
    # Y la diferencia absoluta del peso con la media
    mutate(clase = ifelse(peso > mean(peso), "+", "-"),
           diff = abs(mean(peso)-peso)) %>%
    # Agrupamos por temperatura y mayor o menor a la media
    group_by(temp, clase)  %>%
    # ordenamos descendente por la diferencia con la media
    arrange(desc(diff))  %>%
    # Quitamos los valores mas alejados de cada grupo (1%)
    filter(row_number() > quantile(row_number(),.01)) %>%
    # Desagrupamos y retornamos las columnas originales
    ungroup() %>%
    select(temp, peso)
```

#### Detalle

La idea básica es:

- En primer lugar calculamos la media del peso de cada temperatura
- Armamos una nueva jerarquía en función de si el peso es superior o inferior a la media
- Calculamos la diferencia absoluta con la media y ordenamos en función de ese dato, primero los que estarían más alejados (valores mayores)
- Numeramos cada fila de cada grupo en función del orden
- Usamos `quantile()` para filtrar los valores que sean superiores al 1%.

Comment: Cuando dices "quitamos los valores más alejados de cada grupo", se estarían quitando los más alejados a la media por encima o por abajo?. El caso es que debo depurar mis datos para aplicar los modelos de análisis y de la manera que tengo las funciones no se ajustan demasiado bien a los puntos porque tengo algunos picos horrorosos que me dañan todo. Me han sugerido que haga la limpieza del 1% a ver si mejora.. Gracias por tu explicación @Patricio, muy clara como siempre.

Comment: @Caro, la idea es esa, buscar el 1% eligiendo los valores más alejados de la media, tanto los que están por encima como por debajo.